# ConvertTo-Html modifies a text variable

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a variable contents into a html file, but it gets modified by ConvertTo-Html.
the code:

```
$nb = 10
$text = '<font color="#008000">All ' + $nb + ' test(s) passed</font>'
$file  = "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\test.html"
Write-Host "`$text = "
Write-Host $text
Write-Host
Write-Host "(`$text | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment) ="
$text | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
```

prints:

```
$text = 
<font color="#008000">All 10 test(s) passed</font>

($text | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment) =
<table>
<colgroup><col/></colgroup>
<tr><th>*</th></tr>
<tr><td>50</td></tr>
</table>
```

how can I prevent the modification of my variable $text ?
I'm using powershell 4.0

Comment: What do you expect the `ConvertTo-Html` cmdlet to do? In this case, it will format properties on the string (in this case the length of the string, i.e. 50) into an html formatted string. Your string is already in HTML format, so you don't need to pass it to `ConvertTo-Html`.

Comment: I want to change the text color in some cases, that is why I am passing html code. And I expected that ConvertTo-Html will output something like <table>
<tr><td><font color="#008000">All 10 test(s) passed</font></td></tr>
</table>

Comment: `ConvertTo-Html` will add the properties of the `InputObject` into the table (if you pipe an array to the cmdlet, the table columns will be determined by the first object in the array). Since you are passing a string you'll get the properties of the string into the table. Either just create the HTML manually or create an object which has your string as a property and pipe that object to the `ConvertTo-Html` cmdlet. However, I'm pretty certain that `ConvertTo-Html` would HTML encode your property value, so you still wouldn't get your colourful output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make explicit what Robert.Westerlund said earlier:

Don't use `ConvertTo-HTML` for this operation. Just build your HTML manually. For more info check out this, free, ebook from Don Jones

http://powershell.org/wp/2012/10/24/free-ebook-creating-html-reports-in-powershell/